# How to find out all angular selectors in DOM and store in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular8

## 1) .html

```
<app-root>
<app-header>
dwkjdwjkwd
</app-header>
<app-container>daaddadadad</app-container>
<app-info>diwduiwuwd</app-info>
</app-root>
```

How to find all selector prefixed with `<app-*>` in dom?

## 2) .html

```
<app-root>
<app-header>
</app-header>

<div class="parent">
 oiwdiodw
<app-container>dwww</app-container>
<app-info>dwwdwdwd</app-info>
</div>

</app-root>
```

How to find all selector prefixed with `<app-*>` in dom and inside class 'parent'?

The desired output is ["app-container', 'app-info',.....];

The answer may be in js,jQuery or angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i am not sure how you can use `getElementsByTagName` and filter that tag name like `<app-*` . But what you can do is to get all the elements and then filter them.

See below

```js
var elems = document.body.querySelectorAll(".parent *");
var arr = [...elems].map(elem => elem.tagName.toLowerCase())
  .filter(tagName => tagName.startsWith('app-'))
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<app-root>
  <app-header>
  </app-header>

  <div class="parent">
    oiwdiodw
    <app-container>dwww</app-container>
    <app-info>dwwdwdwd</app-info>
    <span>some span</span>
    <h2>some heading</h2>
  </div>

</app-root>
```

Comment: It is containing the innerHTML as well. Here, just selector name is required.Updated question.

Comment: @Mahi check it now

Answer (score 1):

Query the elements in the container and inspect their `tagName`

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.parent *');
elems.forEach(el => {
  const tag = el.tagName.toLowerCase()
  if (tag.startsWith('app-')) {
    console.log(el);
  }
})
```

```html
<app-root>
  <app-header>
  </app-header>

  <div class="parent">
    <app-container></app-container>
    <app-info></app-info>
  </div>

</app-root>
```

Comment: It is containing the innerHTML as well. Here, just selector name is required.Updated question.

Comment: So use the tagname as selector

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little different implementation:

```js
const tags = Array(...document.querySelectorAll('*'))
 .map(el => el.tagName.toLowerCase())
 .filter(selector => selector.startsWith('app-'));

console.log(tags)
```

```html
<app-root>
<app-header>
</app-header>

<div class="parent">
<app-container></app-container>
<app-info></app-info>
</div>

</app-root>
```

Comment: `localName` from MDN => " This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."

Comment: Also, this is selecting all the elements from the page. Not just the ones from the `parent` class element

Comment: It was asked to be that way: `How to find all selector prefixed with <app-*> in dom ***AND*** inside class 'parent'?`

Comment: well, a lot of questions are unclear. But he also specifies the expected output  ` ["app-container', 'app-info',.....];` . You just have to read between the lines sometimes :) when it comes to questions.